# Как узнать что начался раунд в counter-strike 1.6

Tags: разработка-игр

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно узнать о том что раунд в игре counter-strike 1.6 начался? Писать сниффер для отлова пакетов? читать данные в памяти(наподобие artmoney)? может еще какие способы есть? Если писать сниффер, надо ли для этого ковырять протокол? Язык программирования любой.

Буду рад услышать наиболее легкий способ.  Спасибо.

Comment: > Буду рад услышать наиболее легкий способ  

играй в окне, и будешь видеть, когда заходить

Comment: @cyberdream обновил пост.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запилить плагин, который будет стучать куда-нибудь о том, что начался новый раунд.

Решение "в лоб" на клиенте.

Как я знаю, когда мы сворачиваем игру, а прежде в ней умираем, то при каждом новом раунде курсор мышки перемещается на экране в коодинате 1(х),1(у).

На AutoIT был написан такой костыль:

Все желающие также могут скачать программу у меня в блоге:

[autoIT свернутое окно Counter-Strike и новый раунд.](http://lampacore.ru/2012/12/08/autoit-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-counter-strike-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4/)

Сам код:

```
#cs ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 AutoIt Version: 3.3.8.1
 Author:    lampa

 Script Function:
    Check new round

#ce ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$process = WinGetHandle  ("Counter-Strike");

; проверка на активность приложения
If ProcessExists ($process) == false Then
    MsgBox(0,0, 'hl.exe не запущен!')
    exit;
EndIf

; получаем координаты мышки при старте
$_COORD = MouseGetPos()

; в цикле проверяем, не переместилась ли резко мышь вверх влево
while(1)
    If NOT BitAnd(WinGetState ($process), 16) Then
        Sleep(1000)
        ContinueLoop
    EndIf

    ; раз в 100 мс проверяем координаты мыши
    $_COORD_TMP = MouseGetPos()

    ; если координата top && left на 0 и предыдущая координата top && left <> 0, то
    If $_COORD_TMP[0] == 0 AND $_COORD_TMP[1] == 0 AND  $_COORD[0] <> 0 AND $_COORD[1] <> 0 Then
        $_COORD = $_COORD_TMP;
        MsgBox(0,0, 'Новый раунд');
    ElseIf $_COORD_TMP[0] <> 0 AND $_COORD_TMP[1] <> 0 AND  $_COORD[0] == 0 AND $_COORD[1] == 0 Then
        $_COORD = $_COORD_TMP;
    EndIf

    Sleep(100)
WEnd
```

Comment: Как раз для этого я и хочу написать программу, потому что плагин ставится на сервере, к большинству из которых  у меня доступа нет. Нужно решение на стороне клиента.

Comment: изучить SDK CS, плагины там пишутся,вроде как и для клиентской части

Comment: @cyberdream кхм, по своей памяти я не помню, чтобы было такое реализовано. Сниффер вам поможет только в том случае, если будет запущен клиент игры. Я не помню точно, но HLTV умеет понимать раунды?

Comment: в любом случае это SDK и копать надо отттуда :)

Comment: @thunder я не припоминаю sdk для 1.6

Comment: @lampa, не знаю про HLTV.
А определять начало раунда как раз нужно при запущенном клиенте, ну, что-бы пока валяешься мёртвый можно было хабр читать :) а как раунд начался - Динь - мессаж на экран "Кончай филонить, хватай ствол"

Comment: да, чистый сдк был для карт там...

Comment: @cyberdream на выходных что-нибудь посмотрю.

Comment: @lampa спасибо большое! А то даже не знаю куда копать - моды обычно на стороне сервера работают, веб-мониторы - это постоянно придётся слать запросы на сервер, соответственно дополнительная для него нагрузка, сниффер - рыть протокол?

А если всётаки пытаться прочитать данные из памяти процесса hl.exe? Это ведь намного быстрее выйдет (в плане производительности, работы с сетью ведь нет)

Comment: > пока валяешься мёртвый можно было хабр читать  
забавно. Вы, боюсь, спросить с ботами играете, что пока лежите есть время на серфинг?

Comment: @teanЫЧ фирстом бежит :D и сливают сразу

Comment: @lampa, посоны, прикройте! я рашу)  

Ну в таком случае, при среднестатистическом раундтайме 1.45, даже если гуфаешься в первые 15 секунд (опять же это надо постараться), то есть целых полторы минуты на хабр.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь скачать `amxbans 6.0`, это веб морда на php, там в движке есть модуль для общения с самой игрой, поковыряйся там. И как вариант запилить плагин, что и выше сказал lampa. И как я знаю плагин для amx пилить легче чем для самой игры, amx (как я понял) библотека для общения с игрой.

Comment: Там только мониторинг. Простейшие функции - игроки, карта и т.п.

Comment: вебморда скорее всего работает с БД сервера, к которой клиент обычно подключиться не может

Comment: @cyberdream нет, он работает напрямую с самой игрой

Answer (score 0):

Можно [тут](http://www.amxmodx.org/) посмотреть, сайт специализируется на всяких модах/скриптах/сниппетах и т.п. для всего, что использоует движок valve

Comment: Не, это не то. Если спрашивать, то только на аллиед модс :-)